# Rolling 6 Months

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services, ssms

I have 2 parameters in my report, Month and Year.

I also have a table which in one column has the count of rows for that particular month and another column which has the count of rows for that specific month and the next 5 months (Rolling 6 month).[image]

Both of these columns have an expression which links to the parameters as shown below:

Month Expression:
[image]

6 Month Expression:
[image]
 My parameters use specific values which i have put in (1 - 12) so when my rolling month adds 1 value each time as you can probably guess this wont work when I come near the latter months of the year as my expression does not roll over to next year and just stops at December.

[image]

Overview: Parameters are integer values 1 - 12 and I am not sure how to calculate a rolling 6 months which will carry over to the next year when selecting months late in the year. e.g. If I select November as my Month parameter, my rolling 6 months will only display the sum of rows for November and December, not going to the next year. I am assuming this is because my month values are integers and in my expression I add numbers to the integers for each month therefore my rolling 6 will be trying to add months 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 when obviously months only go to 12.

Comment: Jack are you using TSQL?

Comment: @JithinShaji Not that I am aware of, I think i'm just using normal SQL

Comment: I mean u are using SQL Server, right

Comment: @JithinShaji Yeah, SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question, but looking at this, you may be able to find a solution with SQL itself.

See the query below. Consider this as your report source sql.

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),DT DATE)
INSERT INTO @A (DT) 
VALUES
('2013-01-26'),('2013-02-23'),('2013-03-20'),
('2013-04-23'),('2013-05-23'),('2013-07-23'),
('2013-08-23'),('2013-08-29'),('2013-09-23'),
('2013-12-10'),('2014-03-01')
```

[image]

If you join the result with itself, some what like below, you will get the result in sql query itself, you need to only show it in report. See below.

```
SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,DT) [Y],DATEPART(MONTH,DT) [M],COUNT(*) [ROLLING 6] 
FROM    (
        SELECT  A.*
        FROM    @A A,@A B
        WHERE   ((DATEPART(YEAR,B.DT) * 12) + DATEPART(MONTH,B.DT)) BETWEEN 
                (DATEPART(YEAR,A.DT) * 12) + DATEPART(MONTH,A.DT) AND 
                ((DATEPART(YEAR,A.DT) * 12) + DATEPART(MONTH,A.DT) + 6)) LU
GROUP   BY DATEPART(YEAR,DT),DATEPART(MONTH,DT)
ORDER   BY [Y],[M]
```

[image]

Comment: for sure better way than going for SSRS Expressions according to rule "What can you achieve with SQL, achieve with it" :P

Comment: @JithinShaji Thanks for the response, I will try this way rather than the expressions, it makes much more sense now I think about it.